# CEF Thread Issues - easiest fix?

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded

I'm replacing xulrunner in a C# WinForms app with CEFSharp. Things started off great - I dropped CEF in and had it up and running with little effort.

Now I'm running into problems with the threading and I'm not sure the best way to fix them. I have multiple functions in Javascript that call form code and vice versa. Things like this...

```js
public void ZoomFinished(string data)
{
   try
   {
        bool finished = false;

        if (!_firstTileRun)
        {
            _tileBounds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bounds>(data);  // Save tile from previous run
            Models.PointD nePoint = _tileBounds.NE.Point;
            Models.PointD swPoint = _tileBounds.SW.Point;

            int tileWidth = (int)(nePoint.X - swPoint.X);
            int tileHeight = (int)(swPoint.Y - nePoint.Y);

            // Save tile from previous run
        int mapWidth = this.Width;
        int mapHeight = this.Height;

            Point browserLocation = webBrowser1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
          
           ....
```

When I try to call methods of the web browser, I get complaints that I'm in the wrong thread. Should I be trying to Invoke those calls? Or is it easier to try an run my own message loop to avoid the multiple threads? (there don't seems to be many examples of this though!). Surely there must be a 'proper' way to communicate between the CEF web browser and its host app without running into threading problems?

Comment: In CEF some functions must be called on specific threads, this is stated in documentation comments. There is `CefPostTask` function in CEF to run code on specific thread, see: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?q=cefposttask&unscoped_q=cefposttask